# Pivot SQL query - Show Date in column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

my current query return the below result
[image]

What I need is I have to display date in column header. I know it have to be done using **Pivot**

Example: if we want to display month in column header then query will be something like..

```
SELECT  [January], [February], [March]
FROM    ( SELECT    [Month], SaleAmount
          FROM      Sales
        ) p PIVOT ( SUM(SaleAmount)
                    FOR [Month] 
                      IN ([January],[February],[March])
                  ) AS pvt
```

and I think my resultant query should be look like  `Pivot ( (Price) FOR [DateVal] IN (What will be here?) )` here is what resultant column should be like
[image]

Note: in the result set currently it show December month data, but it can be any month.

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 4**
Ok, now that you posted all your query, and following your comments, you should try this:

```
DECLARE @FirstDay SMALLDATETIME
SELECT @FirstDay = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, (@year + '-' + @month + '-01')); 

WITH Dates AS  
(
  SELECT @FirstDay AS DateVal 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, DateVal) AS DateVal 
  FROM Dates 
  WHERE DATEADD(d, 1, DateVal) < DATEADD(m, 1, @FirstDay)
)

SELECT * INTO #Dates FROM Dates

DECLARE @hotelID INT, @packageID INT, @year VARCHAR(4), @Dates VARCHAR(1000), @month VARCHAR(2), @Query VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @hotelID=248, @packageID=76, @year='2010', @month='12',@Dates=''

SELECT co.*,wb.Name,rc.HotelName 
INTO #HotelData
FROM RCompetitorOccupancy co 
INNER JOIN websites wb ON wb.websiteid=co.websiteid
INNER JOIN RoomCompetitor rc ON rc.competitorid=co.competitorid
WHERE YEAR(occDate)=@year AND MONTH(occdate)=@month AND packageid=@packageID 
AND roomTypeid IN (SELECT roomtypeid FROM CompetitorRoomType WHERE DESCRIPTION=119)

SELECT @Dates = @Dates + '[' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY,DateVal) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DateVal),3)+ '],'
FROM #Dates
GROUP BY Dateval

SET @Dates = LEFT(@Dates,LEN(@Dates)-1)

SET @Query = '
SELECT roomtypeid, description, [Name], [HotelName], '+@Dates+'
FROM (  SELECT  HD.roomtypeid, HD.description, HD.[Name], HD.[HotelName], HD.Price, 
                CAST(DATEPART(DAY,DateVal) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ''-'' + LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DateVal),3) [Date]
        FROM #Dates D
        LEFT JOIN #HotelData HD
        ON D.DateVal = HD.OccDate) T
PIVOT ( SUM(Price) FOR [Date] IN ('+@Dates+') ) AS PT'

EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: your provided answer, I have shown as example in my question. what I need is I want to show date in column like (1Dec,2Dec,3Dec,.....31Dec)

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar Do you always want the result for one month of a year?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar ok, I updated my answer following your comment

Comment: @Lamak, Thanks for your help. if you see the image in the question. My current query return that result set. the query I have wrote in the question that is just for hint and I am thinking I have to use Pivot like in question. Please have a look on image in question. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar Yeah, as I said, I changed my answer to address in a better way your problem, did you try it now?

Comment: Please have a look on my question, I have updated it, I have add an image what I need in resultant column. Thanks

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar Ok, I updated the answer again, please check the query results and tell me if its helping you.

Comment: Hi Lamak, I really thankful for your help. your provided solution is absolutely right. as I have used common table expression before getting actually result and I am have an issue to adjust your solution. If you give me 5 mins, I think it will be resolved easily, I am posting my query in answer. my skype id is toakhtar and I am available now. Thanks Again

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar Unfortunately, I can't connect to skype, the only way I could talk to you is using gmail chat or something like that. In any case, if you keep updating your question, I can try to help you with your problems

Comment: Please tell me your gmail ID?

Comment: I have posted my exact query in answer.

Comment: I have update my answer and commented properly, if you see my answer what I have did, you can analyze. I added you on gmail as well.

Comment: do you need to use CTEs for the tables?, or you can also use temp tables?

Comment: I can use temp tables as well, are you suggesting me to use that?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar Ok, I re-updated my answer. Try that solution and let me know if it helps